# ODBC Connection Issue

Tags: odbc

I have MS Access 2007 database residing in a remote machine. I created network drive for the remote machine in my local machine and created ODBC connection for the database. But when i use the ODBC connection to pull the data from the database, it throws error saying path specified is incorrect. Please help me where i m wrong.

Thanks in advance
Dinesh

Comment: Wild guess: Is the ODBC Connection being made in the same context as the mapped drive was created? E.g. UAC: you created the mapped drive as Yourself (Administrator Token) but the connection is being by Yourself (Normal User Token)? Or you're code is running as a service etc etc.

Comment: I created network drive by name Z:\ and while selecting the database file path i browsed and select from Z:\.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the mapped drive through cmd in administrator mode.